# how to reverse the entire array instead of individual letters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Right now the script is reversing the placement of the first name and last name  which is what I want, and is also reversing the order of each individual letter. The goal is just to reverse the order of the names. Ex, if entering Thomas Jefferson it should output Jefferson, Thomas. Here is my code:

```html
<button onclick="reverseName()">Click here!</button>
<script>
var nameList = [fullName]
function reverseName() {
  var fullName = prompt("enter your first & last name");
  alert(fullName.split("").reverse().join(""));    
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to split on spaces

```js
console.log(
    "Thomas Jefferson".split(" ").reverse().join(", ")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

As it says in the documentation for [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

> If separator is an empty string (`""`), `str` is converted to an array of each of its UTF-16 "characters".

Calling `.split("")` actually splits the string at each character:

```js
console.log("Thomas Jefferson".split(""))
> ['T', 'h', 'o', 'm', 'a', 's', ' ', 'J', 'e', 'f', 'f', 'e', 'r', 's', 'o', 'n' ]
```

As you can see, reversing this list would reverse the whole string. Instead, all you need to do is put a space in there (`.split(" ")`) to split on spaces instead:

```
console.log("Thomas Jefferson".split(" "))
> [ 'Thomas', 'Jefferson' ]
```

Or, you could use the [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) `/\s/` to split on any whitespace (including multiple spaces, tabs, other invisible characters, etc).

```js
function reverseWords(string) {
    return string.split(/\s/).reverse().join(" ")
}
```